# main content body doesn't take up full col-10 width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

using react and bootstrap v5.3.0-alpha1

the main content body when the sidebar isn't collapsed has a gap on the right side - it's not taking up the full width of the page. when i do w-100 or width: 100%, it doesn't apply the p-3 padding and instead the text/elements are becoming hidden. how do i fix this?

```js
import { ConnectKitButton } from "connectkit";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function Holders() {
    const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            setIsSidebarCollapsed(window.innerWidth < 1026);
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        handleResize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                {isSidebarCollapsed ? (
                    <>
                        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                            <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Collapsed Sidebar</span>
                        </nav>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            main content body
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <div className="d-flex p-0 m-0 overflow-hidden">
                            <div className="col-md-2" style={{ width: '250px', height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'yellow', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
                                <div style={{ height: '90%', overflowY: 'auto', background: 'blue' }}>
                                    Sidebar content
                                </div>

                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3" style={{ height: '10%', background: 'yellow', borderTop: '1px solid black' }}>
                                    <ConnectKitButton />
                                    <a href="/#">
                                        <i className="bi bi-sun" id="theme_icon" style={{ fontSize: "1.3rem" }}></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-10 p-3 text-bg-secondary">
                                <h1>Main Content</h1>
                                main content bodymain content bodymain content body
                                main content bodymain content bodymain content body
                                main content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content body
                                main content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content body
                                main content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content bodymain content body
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You should only put `col` elements inside of rows.

Comment: they are inside of a row, no?

Comment: Your question involves layout, so you should show us the compiled HTML rather than making this a React question. It probably has nothing to do with React. Put your HTML and CDN links to Bootstrap in a snippet demo using the editor, then we'll have something to talk about.

Comment: @orange2piece they are not directly inside of the row, they are wrapped around a `d-flex` `div`, which shouldn't inherently cause any issues, just best practice not to do this. Your issue could be related to the fact you are giving the `col-md-10` it's own padding and also the fact you are specifying the width in the `col-md-2` element.